# picture format in android

Tags: android

I am new to android I would like to ask a question which may not be up to the priority. The question is: I found android accepting only *.png files. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It accepts *.jpg as well just save it as optimised for web in photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

PNG (Portable Network Graphics) are usually light weight and transparent images. Thats the reason.